# ExtJs customization

Tags: javascript, extjs, customization

In a customized ExtJs file, I found the following code. Actually what is doing in the following code.

This code is written in an xtype.js file and which is included in the jsp page.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'js/ext-ux');

Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.field.ComboBox'
]);

Ext.define('Ext.ux.UDComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.udComboBox',
    directArgs : false,
    skipValue : false,
    firstOptionDefault : false,
    forceSelection : true,
    typeAhead : true,
    queryMode : 'local',
    triggerAction : 'all',
    selectOnFocus : true,
    allowBlank : false,
    emptyText : '-Select One-',
    valueField : '',
    lastQuery : '', // This is used with store.filter function.
    returnAsObject : true,
    fieldStyle: 'background-image: none;',
    msgTarget:'side',
    hideTrigger:false,// if true hide the drop down icon
    skipFirstOption : false
});
```

And in our file, for creating combobox, we use `xtype: 'udComboBox'`.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I could not understand the portion Ext.define('Ext.ux.UDComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.udComboBox',

Comment: That code is just declaring a class named `Ext.ux.UDComboBox` which derives from the built-in combobox and whose xtype is `udComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('<TopLevel.path.NameSpace>', 'js/ext-ux'); }
// Namespace by convention should be in lower case
Ext.define('<TopLevel.path.NameSpace>.<ComponentName>', { 
     extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox', 
     // alias by convention should be in lower case
     alias: 'widget.<componentname>'
});
}
```

- Top-level namespaces and constructors  names should be UpperCamelCase
- Alias xtype should be in lower case

So a example of your configuration can be: your company

```
// --Filename: app/js/components/UdComboBox.js <-Filename as Name
Ext.define('MyCompany.libs.UdComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.udcombobox',
    ....
});

// --Filename: app/app.js
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('MyCompany.libs', 'js/components');

Ext.require([
        //This is only because we are instantiate by xtype, if you use Ext.create this is not need it.
        'MyCompany.libs.UdComboBox'
    ]);

Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.create("Ext.container.Viewport", {
            layout: 'fit',
             items : [{
                 xtype : "udcombobox"
             }]
         });
});

// --Filename: app/app2.js
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('MyCompany.libs', 'js/components');


Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.create("Ext.container.Viewport", {
            layout: 'fit',
             items : [{
                 xtype : "panel"
             }, 
             new Ext.Create('MyCompany.libs.UdComboBox',{
                ..config..
             })
            ]
         });
});
```